# laravel 5.4 login attempts don't work

Tags: laravel

I am trying to limit my login attempts but still not working

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

and this is ThrottlesLogin.php

```
  protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
            $this->throttleKey($request), 3, 2
        );
    }
```

and i know in laravel 5.4 the AuthenticatesUsers call by default thethrottlesLogin but still dont limit login attempts.
and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ThrottlesLogin`s trait in `LoginController`